# How do I crop my screen's working area?

Tags: windows, display, crop

I have a particular need concerning display management in Windows.

I have a broken display, and I want to use only one part of the screen, even with full screen apps.

A bit like this:

```
 ______________________
|                      |
| B   _____________    |
| R  |             |   |
| O  |   USABLE    |   |
| K  |    AREA     |   |
| E  |             |   |
| N  |             |   |
|    |_____________|   |
|                      |
|   PART               |
|______________________|
```

I know that there is a software called PowerStrip that does this, but it is not compatible with my graphic card.

Is there any way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you found any solution OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen nvidia graphics cards have the ability to move/crop in the nvidia control panel seen here:

[image]

I'm assuming ATI based cards probably have the same feature.

If you could be more specific on your computer graphics card, that would help answer the question from this direction.